# Django include tag

Tags: python, django, include

We are using django with python. I am facing a problem with include tag. I want to include a header in all modules of application.
In application templates directory contains all the html files with  subfolders of modules. In any sub-module if I am creating header html and including this tag in base.html  then it is working. 
But if I place the header html in parent directory, its not working for any sub-modules. 
I even tried `{% include "../header.html" %}` in html with django template, but no luck.

The project structure fo my application, in which root directory I have templates, static, handlers folder. Inside templates I have `sub1` and `sub2` folders. In sub1 I have base.html and in templates parent directory base.html, header.html, index.html. See below:

```
Root
----templates
----------Sub1
-----------------base.html
----------Sub2
----------base.html
----------header.html
----------index.html
----static
----handlers
```

Answer (score 3):

Django templates include tag does not recognize relative paths. You need to give it the path under your templates directory, so try using the following instead:

```
{% include "Sub2/header.html" %}
```

**Update:**

Seems like your "header.html" are on the "Sub2" level and not inside it i.e. it's directly under templates directory So you should try:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

Comment: For the record Django 1.10 now support relative paths for include and extends https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: This answer is out of date now. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#extends (the description for how relative imports for include points to the example in extends)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood you. Just try `{% include "header.html" %}`, the search of django template should start from template folder.

The template folder is configured in Django config file "setting.py".

`TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')`

In addition, I have a project which can seprate Django template develop from the back-end using webpack and support jade, es6 and scss. The readme is in chinese :(, but you can run the project and check the source code.

https://github.com/njleonzhang/webpack-django-starter

Comment: I tried {% include "header.html" %} this too, not sure whether templates files has to be loader first or no.